# Jquery toggle is not working while creating a table through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Insted of creating table  using the while loop, if I am writting the html  inside body tag than the toggle button is working but if I am creating the table using while loop the toggle button is not working not working.

```
<script src="../assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../PurpleStyle/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        debugger;
        $('.jq_show_table').toggle(function () {
            $(this).text('Hide');
            $(".tab_taggle").show();

        }, function () {
            $(".tab_taggle").hide();
            $(this).text('Show');
        }
        );

   function GetLocations() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Location.aspx/GetLocations",
            type: "POST",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) { debugger; BindLocation(data.d); },
            error: function (data) { BindLocation(data.d); },
        });
    }
 function BindLocation(locationList) {
        debugger;
        var table = "<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='table'>";
        table += "<tr class='tab_head'>";
        table += "<td width='7%'>User name</td>";

        table += "<td width='4%'>Form</td>";
        table += "<td width='13%'>Places Visited</td>";
        table += "<td width='7%' align='center'>Setings</td>";
        table += "</tr>";
        table += "<tr>";
        table += "<td valign='middle'>" + "User Name" + "</td>";
        table += "<td valign='middle'>Form  </td>";
        table += "<td valign='middle'>Places Visited</td>";
        table += "<td class='no-padding'>";

        table += "<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='tab_taggle'>";
        table += "<tr><td width='54%'>GPS</td><td width='46%' class='off'>Off</td></tr>";
        table += "<tr><td>Phone Network</td><td class='off'>Off</td></tr>";
        table += "<tr><td>Auto Start</td><td class='on'>Off</td></tr>";
        table += "<tr><td>Auto Start</td><td class='on'>Off</td></tr>";
        table += "<tr><td>Connection</td><td class='on'>Off</td></tr>";
        table += "</table>";

        table += "<a class='btn btn_grey jq_show_table' href='#'>Show</a>"
        table += "</td>";
        table += "</tr>";
        // }
        table += "</table>";
        $('#onTable').html(table);
    }
```

```
            <div class="tab_container">

                <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
                    <div class="heading">ON</div>
                    <div id="onTable"></div>

                </div>
```

Comment: you are missing    });   at the end of your script

Comment: No @osama that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply put, you are trying to bind the event listener to a non existing element. In order to fix it, you should set event listener after you rendered that table to #onTable div. So if i were you, i would create a function to bind the event listener like so;

```
var initListener = function(){
    $('.jq_show_table').toggle(function () {
        $(this).text('Hide');
        $(".tab_taggle").show();

    }, function () {
        $(".tab_taggle").hide();
        $(this).text('Show');
    });
}
```

And then, between the closing tag and `$('#onTable').html(table);` line of `BindLocation` function, i would call it like: `initListener();`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to change `toggle` to `click` and since your element will be added dynamically you need to have `event delegation` here. So make some changes as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#onTable').on('click','.jq_show_table',function () {
    //Event Delegation
    var text=$(this).text();
    //get the text of element
    if(text=='Show')//if show
    {
      $(this).text('Hide');
      $(".tab_taggle").show();
    }
    else //if hide
    {
      $(".tab_taggle").hide();
      $(this).text('Show');
    }
  })

 function BindLocation() {
        debugger;
        var table = "<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='table'>";
        table += "<tr class='tab_head'>";
        table += "<td width='7%'>User name</td>";

        table += "<td width='4%'>Form</td>";
        table += "<td width='13%'>Places Visited</td>";
        table += "<td width='7%' align='center'>Setings</td>";
        table += "</tr>";
        table += "<tr>";
        table += "<td valign='middle'>" + "User Name" + "</td>";
        table += "<td valign='middle'>Form  </td>";
        table += "<td valign='middle'>Places Visited</td>";
        table += "<td class='no-padding'>";

        table += "<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='tab_taggle'>";
        table += "<tr><td width='54%'>GPS</td><td width='46%' class='off'>Off</td></tr>";
        table += "<tr><td>Phone Network</td><td class='off'>Off</td></tr>";
        table += "<tr><td>Auto Start</td><td class='on'>Off</td></tr>";
        table += "<tr><td>Auto Start</td><td class='on'>Off</td></tr>";
        table += "<tr><td>Connection</td><td class='on'>Off</td></tr>";
        table += "</table>";

        table += "<a class='btn btn_grey jq_show_table' href='#'>Show</a>"
        table += "</td>";
        table += "</tr>";
        // }
        table += "</table>";
        $('#onTable').html(table);
    }
  BindLocation();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab_container">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    <div class="heading">ON</div>
    <div id="onTable"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the toggle part in the success of the ajax because you are binding the toggle to an element that doesn't exist in the DOM yet

```
function GetLocations() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Location.aspx/GetLocations",
            type: "POST",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) { debugger; BindLocation(data.d); 

            $('.jq_show_table').toggle(function () {
                 $(this).text('Hide');
                 $(".tab_taggle").show();

             }, function () {
             $(".tab_taggle").hide();
             $(this).text('Show');
           });
 },
            error: function (data) { BindLocation(data.d); },
        });
    }
```